# Як правильно перекласти "method dispatch"?

Tags: переклад, from-english, терміни

Як правильно перекладається "method dispatch"?

Зараз читаю курс з програмування на мові R. Зустрів цей термін, але зрозумілого перекладу не знайшов. Варіант з транслітерацією - це не зовсім те, що треба.

Comment: А що цей термін означає? Значення збігається з описаним тут: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1805510/694852 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Переклад через пояснення:

**Процес/алгоритм визначення відповідного методу**

---

Method Dispatch - алгоритм визначення того, який саме метод потрібно викликати в залежності від того, які параметри були надіслані (у випадку з R важливим також є тип цих параметрів).

Я не зустрічав усталеного перекладу цього терміну українською.

У Вікіпідручнику [вживається](https://uk.wikibooks.org/wiki/Scala/Coursera/%D0%9E%D0%B1%E2%80%99%D1%94%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8) термін без перекладу:

> Dynamic method dispatch - код який викликається при виклику метода,
>   залежить від конкретного типу об’єктів що викликаються.

В статті [Таблиця віртуальних методів](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8F_%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%80%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%85_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%96%D0%B2) використовується слово `диспетчеризація`:

> Однак, віртуальні таблиці дозволяють одиничну **диспетчеризацію** (англ.
>   single dispatch), за спеціальним параметром this, на відміну від
>   множинної диспетчеризації (як в CLOS або Dylan), де тип параметра
>   береться до уваги під час диспетчеризації.