# Як перекласти "dispatch signature"?

Tags: переклад, from-english, терміни

Як перекласти "dispatch signature"?

Вивчаю матеріали [тут](http://www.bioconductor.org/help/course-materials/2010/AdvancedR/S4InBioconductor.pdf).

Comment: Ukrainian SE — не перекладацький сервіс. Взагалі вважається добрим, коли Ви показуєте, що саме Ви зробили для самостійного вирішення проблеми — але справа навіть не в цьому. Вам слід пояснити, **що саме мається на увазі** під «dispatch signature». Бо інтерпретація чужомовних текстів/термінів, на жаль, за межами предметної області UkrSE. Тобто, якщо Ви **розумієте**, що мається на увазі під «dispatch signature» — але не знаєте, який найкращий український еквівалент цього терміну, — ласкаво просимо (але, будь ласка, поясність спочатку іншим, щоби їм було простіше підібрати еквівалент).

Comment: Якщо ж Ви **не розумієте**, що таке «dispatch signature», — то це не до нас — це, можливо, до EnglishSE або взагалі не до SE. Ми не займаємося допомогою в розборі іноземних текстів — Ви маєте вже розуміти зміст; але ми з радістю допоможемо, якщо Ви не знаєте, як *зрозумілий Вам зміст найкраще передати українською*. **Відчуваєте різницю?**

Comment: @Sasha 
Дякую за наведену нижче відповідь. Стосовно чому я це написав - зробити переклад лобовою транслітерацією типу "signature" в "сигнатуру" можно без проблем. я б сюди й не писав. А от знайти український відповідник, який нормально описує явище нормальною мовою - оце якраз й проблема. А писати непотріб на кшталт "імплементація" замість "впровадження, застосування" вважаю неправильним.

Comment: @Sasha
я усвідомлюю, що технічну українську можливо треба ще унормовувати. можли треба викидати "переклад" у вигляді транслітерації, бо це почасти спотворює розуміння.

Comment: Я вище зовсім не про те писав. А про те, що Ви анітрошечки не спростили людям завдання, написавши (дослівно): «як перекласти „dispatch signature“? вивчаю матеріали тут.» Вам треба було пояснити: «От є термін „dispatch signature“, він позначає теє, теє і теє. Як його краще передати українською, щоби <таким-то умовам задовольнити>?» Бо створюється враження, що Ви самі не знаєте, що таке «dispatch signature», і хочете, щоби Вам пояснили, а не шукаєте український відповідник. Ну [ось](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/1003/4) хоча б приклад.

Comment: @ Sasha
дякую за коментар та за приклад. справді треба було додати ще посилання на джерела де я дивився.  а то вставив лише посилання на джерело.

Comment: Вам у першу чергу треба було додати **пояснення**, що таке «dispatch signature» (щоби спростити роботу іншим і розширити аудиторію до тих, хто не пам'ятає без підказки, що це таке — але корисні думки надати може). І Ви ще можете його додати (**edit**) — бо я бачу, що Вас мінусують і мінусують.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Просто як жест доброї волі.

Це *сигнатура*, за якою відбувається *[диспетчеризація функції](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/894/4)*, тобто відбувається *визначення того, яку саме з можливих реалізацій функції треба викликати*. (В багатьох мовах функції, що вимагають диспетчеризації, а не дозволяють прямий виклик, називаються віртуальними, а вибір реалізації, тобто диспетчеризація, відбувається через таблицю віртуальних методів.)

Під *сигнатурою* мається на увазі якийсь набір характеристик функції (вважай «відбиток пальців»), за яким можна проводити диспетчеризацію, тобто визначати, яку саме з можливих реалізацій треба викликати. В Java, а також багатьох інших мовах, сигнатурою функції вважається назва функції + послідовність типів її параметрів (оскільки в одному класі може бути декілька функцій з однією назвою і різними кількостями/типами параметрів — а от двох функцій з повністю однаковими назвою і послідовністю типів параметрів (в одному класі) бути не може).